# Cartesian equations from given hyperplanes

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a question that says...

Give Cartesian equations of the given hyperplanes:

A. **x**$  =(-1,2) + t(3,2)$

B. the plane passing through (2,0,1) and orthogonal to the line **x**=(2,-1,3)+t(1,2,-2)

For part a, I have...

found the normal vector a=(2,-3) since (2,-3) $\cdot$ (3,2) =0 and you want a $\cdot$ x = 0. So the cartesian equation would then be...

$2x_{1} - 3x_{2}$
Is this right or have I misunderstood a concept?

As for part b, I'm totally lost. I know I want my answer to be in similar form as in a, but I'm confused on how you use the information you're given. Could someone please explain.

Comment: You don’t have an equation yet. You’ve got an expression that might be one side of an equation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hints:**

(a) Equations need equal signs. What does your expression equal? The constant that you pick will ensure that your hyperplane actually passes through at least one of the points that the given line does (and isn't merely parallel to the given line).

(b) As in part (a), we need the plane's normal vector. This vector should be perpendicular to every vector lying in the plane. But we already know that the given line is orthogonal to the plane, so just use its direction vector. Finally, as in part (a), choose your constant in such a way that your candidate hyperplane actually passes through the given point.

Comment: I guess I'm still confused on how to choose the constant, can you explain a little more. Also in (a) how do I go about determining what my expression is equal to?

Comment: Suppose that $2x_1 - 3x_2 = k$ for some constant $k$. We know that the line passes through a particular point. Plug this point into the equation to solve for $k$.